# Error on page 4 Enderton’s elements of set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

He writes:

> Let $U_s$ be set of all people in the United States, and let $U_n$ be the set of all countries belonging to the United Nations. Then
> John Jones $\in U_s \in U_n$.

But $U_s$ is the set of all people in the United States. It is not, however, a country.  Therefore, how can it be an element of $U_n$?

Comment: I think the line says that John Jones is in Us AND Us is in Un. The operator E is used twice. First on John Jones and Us and then on Us and Un.

Comment: That was my guess. But  surprised that that is the correct way to  read it, so it’s not analogous to reading a>b>c ?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation and https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. Search for "latex belongs to" to find the right command.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Enderton is conflating the set of people who live in the United States with the country itself.  It would have been better to let $U_n$ be the set of people who live in any nation on Earth.

Comment: That was my read, I.e. conflating Us with The United States. I checked an errata page but that was not picked up.

Comment: An (arguably) more natural resolution is to distinguish between the country $(C) =$ United States and the people living in the United States $P_C$, by introducing a Map $M$ that operates on people $p$.  So $M(p) = C \iff p \in P_C.$  Then, $p \in P_C \implies M(p) \in U_n.$

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I don't think that's the proper resolution here, as then we should have $U_s \subseteq U_n$, not $U_s \in U_n$. You would also lose the joke about "U.N. = $U_n$".